# How to pass parameter in the ctm API url?

Tags: php, curl

I am using CTM API for my web application. URL of docs is [here](https://postman.calltrackingmetrics.com/#58876022-1920-4796-9361-13547b418234). I am fetching data for list of activities and data arrived. But when I am passing parameters i.e. `start_date` and `end_date` the data does not change and only 10 rows are fetched and displayed.

My code is:

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.calltrackingmetrics.com/api/v1/accounts/'.$sub_account_id.'/calls?start_date='.$start_date.'&end_date='.$end_date,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      'Authorization: Basic '.$encoded_string,
      'Content-Type: application/json'
    ),
  ));
```

I am passing `start_date` and `end_date` parameters but receiving on first 10 rows. Am I doing something wrong?

Please guide me to this docs if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Can you show the result, there might be a next page URL (something like `"next_page": "/api/v1/accounts/18600/users?page=2",` from one of the examples which you could call.

Comment: "total_entries":94,"total_pages":10,"per_page":10,"stats":{},"after":"MTY5NDE3OTk4Ng==","next_page":"https://api.calltrackingmetrics.com/api/v1/accounts/123456/calls?after=MTY5NDE3OTk4Ng%3D%3D\u0026end_date=2023-09-13\u0026page=2\u0026start_date=2023-08-14"}

Comment: okay so results are there but in the next page. how can i integrate it to view efficiently in a table?

Comment: Okay now i got the answer and i have used while loop to iterate and get all contains from array. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL looks fine and if you are receiving first 10 rows only then the result is also fine. As per my perception from going through docs. There might be next page url in the response. And you can get all rows by iterating through loop while getting data from next page URL until the end page. You can do something like this

```
$i=1; 
  $result_calls = array();
  $result = "";
  
  do {
     curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => empty($result)? 'https://api.calltrackingmetrics.com/api/v1/accounts/'.$sub_account_id.'/calls?start_date='.$start_date.'&end_date='.$end_date : $result['next_page'],
      
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: Basic '.$encoded_string,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
      ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    $result = json_decode($response, true);

    foreach ($result['calls'] as $key => $value) {
      array_push($result_calls, $value); 
    }

    
    $i++;

   } while ($i <= $result['total_pages']);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks man. I was trying something like this, but your answer is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending the parameters in other way i.e.

```
$pData["account_id"]=$account_id;
$pData["start_date"]=$start_date;
$pData["end_date"]=$end_date;

CURLOPT_POST => true,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $pData,
```

Comment: No that's not working. I think we can't use post request there.